# How can I get VM instance running time in openstack via python API?

Tags: python, openstack-nova

I need a small billing report for the usage of the VMs inside openstack after it is stopped, so far I already find the way to get flavor information (vCPU, disk, memory) from instance name.

And I want to know the VM's startup time to calculate now.

Are there any good ways to fetch it from openstack python API ?

It will be nice if you can paste the code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I got the answer from [china-openstack community](http://groups.google.com/group/china-openstack-user-group), and shared here)

In the [novaclient usage module](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-novaclient/api/novaclient.v1_1.usage.html#novaclient.v1_1.usage.Usage), all the instance (active or terminated) can be fetched by `list` API, the detail information is fetched via `get` API, it is not clear what information are exposed via this python document.

Fortunately the [openstack api : os-simple-tenant-usage](http://api.openstack.org/api-ref.html#ext-os-simple-tenant-usage) tells the data structure, the `uptime` is what I want.

```
 "tenant_usage": {
    "server_usages": [
        {
            ... (skipped)
            "uptime": 3600,
            "vcpus": 1
        }
    ],
```

openstack dashboard (at least Folsom version) use this API as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to retrieve server's uptime. I mean real uptime for the time the server has been UP, not since its creation.

- I created a new machine, the machine was running and I was getting some *update* value; this was nicely incremented
- Then I stopped the machine and issued the request again: The response correctly reports *"state": "stopped"*, but the *uptime* attr. is still being incremented. ==> Again, in this extension it is not uptime, it is time from creation

Request to the *os-simple-tenant-usage* extension (after obtaining an auth. token): 
`GET http://rdo:8774/v2/4e1900cf21924a098709c23480e157c0/os-simple-tenant-usage/4e1900cf21924a098709c23480e157c0` (with the correct tenant ID)

Response (notice the machine is stopped and uptime is a non-zero value):

```
{
    "tenant_usage": {
        "total_memory_mb_usage": 0.000007111111111111112,
        "total_vcpus_usage": 1.388888888888889e-8,
        "start": "2014-02-25T14:20:19.660179",
        "tenant_id": "4e1900cf21924a098709c23480e157c0",
        "stop": "2014-02-25T14:20:19.660184",
        "server_usages": [
            {
                "instance_id": "ca4465a8-38ca-40de-b138-82efcc88c7cf",
                "uptime": 1199,
                "started_at": "2014-02-25T14:00:20.000000",
                "ended_at": null,
                "memory_mb": 512,
                "tenant_id": "4e1900cf21924a098709c23480e157c0",
                "state": "stopped",
                "hours": 1.388888888888889e-8,
                "vcpus": 1,
                "flavor": "m1.tiny",
                "local_gb": 1,
                "name": "m1"
            }
        ],
        "total_hours": 1.388888888888889e-8,
        "total_local_gb_usage": 1.388888888888889e-8
    }
}
```

So despite its name **uptime** it is just **time since the server creation**.

Comment: Larry, no, I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [metadata](http://docs.openstack.org/api/openstack-compute/2/content/Server_Metadata-d1e2529.html) :

> Custom server metadata can also be supplied at launch time.

At creation you can save a date time, then when it starts up you can calculate a difference.

Comment: thx, interesting, never though metadata can go this as well, and I think there shall already exist API for it, so don't want to add new stuff