# Machine's uptime in OpenStack

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

I would like to know (and retrieve via REST API) the uptime of individual VMs running in OpenStack.

I was quite surprised that OpenStack web UI has a colon called "Uptime" but it actually show time since the VM was created. If i stop the VM, the UI shows Status=Shutoff, Power State=Shutdown, but the Uptime is still being incremented...

Is there a "real" uptime (I mean for a machine that is UP)?
Can I retrieve it somehow via the OpenStack's REST API?

I saw the comment at [How can I get VM instance running time in openstack via python API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139362/how-can-i-get-vm-instance-running-time-in-openstack-via-python-api/18172866#18172866) but the page with the extension mentioned there does not exists and it looks to me that this extension will not be available in all OpenStack environment. I would like to have some standard way to retrieve the uptime.

Thanks.

(Version Havana)

Comment: Actually the  os-simple-tenant-usage extension does not work either: thhe "uptime" attribute is still being increased even though the machine is stopped and "state": "stopped". The "uptime" is just "time since creation" again.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any documentation saying this is the reason, but the nova-scheduler doesn't differentiate between a running and powered off instance.  So your cloud can't be over-allocated or leave an instance in a position that would be unable to be powered on.  I would like to see a metric of actual system runtime as well, but at the moment the only way to gather that would be through ceilometer or via Rackspaces [StackTach](https://github.com/rackerlabs/stacktach)